# How to get one value from sqlite database android?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

Trying to run this code :

```
AppsDbHelper dbHelper = new AppsDbHelper(mContext);
            SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

            String query = "select launch from apps where name=com.google.android.apps.maps";
            Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery( query, null );
```

But face to such exeption:

`android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: select launch from apps where name=com.google.android.apps.maps`

What's the problem and how I can fix it?

Thanks for every answer in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try wrapping the com.google.android.apps.maps in single quote --> '

```
String query = "select launch from apps where name='com.google.android.apps.maps'";
```